# How to allocate an ID

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I want to get user ID 5005 for myself. I read that with GAE you can allocate an ID and set it but I don't fully understand the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html).

The code is

```
handmade_key = db.Key.from_path('MyModel', 1)
first_batch = db.allocate_ids(handmade_key, 10)
first_range = range(first_batch[0], first_batch[1] + 1)

my_id = first_range.pop(0)
new_key = db.Key.from_path('MyModel', my_id)
new_instance = MyModel(key=new_key)
new_instance.put()
assert new_instance.key().id() == my_id
```

But where do I put that I want 5005 as the user ID? The model is the user model from webapp2.

Comment: It is a function used to 'reserve' a set of IDs, such that no other entities will be given the same key [which could cause a conflict]. AFAIK, you cannot set your own 'id' to an entity [although, I must ask, why would you require such a functionality?]

Comment: My manager wants to make up a simple ID eg. 5005 and assign it the somebody instead of eg. 9384637 when there are only 2 users or so. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate specific ids range using [allocate_id_range](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html), and then you should be able to construct the Key manually using [Key.from_path](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_from_path) by supplying your own id, and assign it to your new Model instance using the `key` argument.